# Cannot use Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I'm currently using Eclipse Mars and I'm trying to install Scala IDE plugin but, after installing, I can't see nothing. The prompt with setup diagnostics doesn't open at startup, there's no Scala menu item in preferences of Eclipse and I haven't any option to create a Scala project/file, no Scala perspective.

In installation details I can see Scala IDE already installed, that's the URL I've used to install:
Scala IDE - http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/stable/site

My Eclipse Mars has another installed plugins as STS, JBoss tools and Android ADT

Any idea? Thanks!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you start Eclipse on a console, do you see any error messages?

Comment: nothing, the console is clean. i tried in two different computers with same result

Comment: Did you install all the plugins by yourself. If yes, It would be nice if you could start again from an empty installation, add Scala IDE and then all the other plugins and check at which point it starts to disappear. Maybe there is a conflict between one of the plugins.

Comment: I did that and now it's working, thanks, but i think it's not a conflict, i used the new eclipse installer and i noticed that eclipse folder in program files never grown and files were placed apparently on user folder. Now I used traditional zip eclipse base, and i've installed first STS then Scala IDE. Now it's working. I'm not sure if this was the problem (permission?), but now everything it's working.